# two divs one below the other each one 50% height

Tags: html, css

I need to build a structure of two div's one below the other each of them need to be 50% height and they need to have a margin of 20px height between then.

is it possible to do it without js?

Comment: Its simple css. What do you think not possible? Show us the code that you're having problem with.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using viewport units (`vh`) as follows.

Set the height of each div to `50vh` which will take 50% of the screen height.

However, to get the 20px margin, you need to reduce the height of each div by 10px to make room for the margin.

Since you are mixing units, you need to use the CSS `calc` function, which
may not be as well supported by browsers as you need.

If that is the case, try setting a margin height in `vh` units, and then you can omit `calc`.

Be aware of the enclosing block that contains your div's.  In my example, I set the margins of the `body` to zero to prevent vertical scrolling (which I assume you don't want).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.top {
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: calc(50vh - 10px);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: calc(50vh - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="top">Top...</div>
<div class="bottom">Bottom...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

HTML

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

CSS

```
.one, .two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}
.one {
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.two {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 50vh;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```